# Getting Error Resource Not Found Exception while using velocity

Tags: spring, velocity

Not able to attach the template for sending the mail..

-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" 
    class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
             <value>
              resource.loader=class
              class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
             </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="velocityConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">

        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/"/>

</bean>

    <bean id="velocityviewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/velocity/"
          p:suffix=".vm" />
</beans>
```

code :
The error is pointing to this line which i am using in my Service implementation

```
String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "mailtemplate", model);
```

I am getting an error saying not able to find any resource

The complete stack trace of error is:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'mailtemplate'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:354)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1400)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:370)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:345)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(VelocityEngineUtils.java:122)
    at service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl.sendMail(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:110)
    at controllers.TrainingInvitationController.sendMail(TrainingInvitationController.java:54)
    at controllers.TrainingInvitationController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$176c7e66.invoke()
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
    at controllers.TrainingInvitationController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b58c7689.sendMail()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:313)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:445)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:356)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:627)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:141)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:269)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:430)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:701)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:617)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:199)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.HttpChannelEndPoint.run(HttpChannelEndPoint.java:270)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:475)
```

Now how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please post the full error log.

Comment: I have edited the post.. you can find the error stack above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.. i got an idea from the velocity docs itself..

I was needed to modify only in velocity bean configuration.. See Below for what i have changed.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
<property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/"/>
</bean>
```

Thats it... now its working perfect for me..

Comment: From the Spring doc's, you might need to prepend the path with "classpath:" for Spring to find those resources for you.